# gRPC client failing to connect to server with TLS certificates

Tags: python, ssl, grpc

I am trying to establish encrypted connection with TLS certificates using gRPC. With insecure connection everything works fine, also I tried to use client written on Go, it works too. But with Python I am getting following error:

```
grpc._channel._Rendezvous: <_Rendezvous of RPC that terminated with:
        status = StatusCode.UNAVAILABLE
        details = "failed to connect to all addresses"
        debug_error_string = "{"created":"@1565190346.229323178","description":"Failed to pick subchannel","file":"src/core/ext/filters/client_channel/client_channel.cc","file_line":3528,"referenced_errors":
[{"created":"@1565190346.229314131","description":"failed to connect to all addresses","file":"src/core/ext/filters/client_channel/lb_policy/pick_first/pick_first.cc","file_line":399,"grpc_status":14}]}"
```

Here is my client's code:

```py
credentials = grpc.ssl_channel_credentials()
channel = grpc.secure_channel('127.0.0.1:9332', credentials)
stub = srv_pb2_grpc.SrvStub(channel)
response = stub.Action(msg='msg')
```

Any suggestions?

**Update**

Here is the output with `GRPC_TRACE` and `GRPC_VERBOSITY` environment variables.

```py
os.environ['GRPC_TRACE'] = 'transport_security,tsi'
os.environ['GRPC_VERBOSITY'] = 'DEBUG'
```

```
I0808 11:24:21.077552208   28357 ev_epoll1_linux.cc:116]     grpc epoll fd: 3                                                                                                                                        
D0808 11:24:21.077580061   28357 ev_posix.cc:174]            Using polling engine: epoll1                                                                                                                            
D0808 11:24:21.077622131   28357 dns_resolver_ares.cc:483]   Using ares dns resolver                                                                                                                                 
E0808 11:24:21.077633004   28357 trace.cc:65]                Unknown trace var: 'transport_security'                                                                                                                 
I0808 11:24:21.402168083   28357 ssl_transport_security.cc:217]      HANDSHAKE START -       TLS client start_connect  - !!!!!!                                                                                      
I0808 11:24:21.402353776   28357 ssl_transport_security.cc:217]                 LOOP -    TLS client enter_early_data  - !!!!!!                                                                                      
I0808 11:24:21.402387194   28357 ssl_transport_security.cc:217]                 LOOP -   TLS client read_server_hello  - !!!!!!                                                                                      
I0808 11:24:21.606877030   28357 ssl_transport_security.cc:217]                 LOOP - TLS client read_server_certifi  - !!!!!!                                                                                      
I0808 11:24:21.607580283   28357 ssl_transport_security.cc:217]                 LOOP - TLS client read_certificate_st  - !!!!!!                                                                                      
I0808 11:24:21.607612862   28357 ssl_transport_security.cc:217]                 LOOP - TLS client verify_server_certi  - !!!!!!                                                                                      
I0808 11:24:21.613300944   28357 ssl_transport_security.cc:217]                 LOOP - TLS client read_server_key_exc  - !!!!!!                                                                                      
I0808 11:24:21.614718867   28357 ssl_transport_security.cc:217]                 LOOP - TLS client read_certificate_re  - !!!!!!                                                                                      
I0808 11:24:21.614762602   28357 ssl_transport_security.cc:217]                 LOOP - TLS client read_server_hello_d  - !!!!!!                                                                                      
I0808 11:24:21.614782664   28357 ssl_transport_security.cc:217]                 LOOP - TLS client send_client_certifi  - !!!!!!                                                                                      
I0808 11:24:21.614798210   28357 ssl_transport_security.cc:217]                 LOOP - TLS client send_client_key_exc  - !!!!!!
I0808 11:24:21.616791101   28357 ssl_transport_security.cc:217]                 LOOP - TLS client send_client_certifi  - !!!!!!
I0808 11:24:21.616817014   28357 ssl_transport_security.cc:217]                 LOOP - TLS client send_client_finishe  - !!!!!!
I0808 11:24:21.616891441   28357 ssl_transport_security.cc:217]                 LOOP -       TLS client finish_flight  - !!!!!!
I0808 11:24:21.616916680   28357 ssl_transport_security.cc:217]                 LOOP - TLS client read_session_ticket  - !!!!!!
I0808 11:24:21.811575115   28357 ssl_transport_security.cc:217]                 LOOP - TLS client process_change_ciph  - !!!!!!
I0808 11:24:21.811645429   28357 ssl_transport_security.cc:217]                 LOOP - TLS client read_server_finishe  - !!!!!!
I0808 11:24:21.811706483   28357 ssl_transport_security.cc:217]                 LOOP - TLS client finish_client_hands  - !!!!!!
I0808 11:24:21.811745454   28357 ssl_transport_security.cc:217]                 LOOP -                TLS client done  - !!!!!!
I0808 11:24:21.811763000   28357 ssl_transport_security.cc:217]       HANDSHAKE DONE -                TLS client done  - !!!!!!
D0808 11:24:21.811984315   28357 security_handshaker.cc:176] Security handshake failed: {"created":"@1565252661.811954686","description":"Cannot check peer: missing selected ALPN property.","file":"src/core/lib/security/security_connector/ssl_utils.cc","file_line":129}
I0808 11:24:21.812313765   28357 subchannel.cc:1031]         Connect failed: {"created":"@1565252661.811954686","description":"Cannot check peer: missing selected ALPN property.","file":"src/core/lib/security/security_connector/ssl_utils.cc","file_line":129}
```

Comment: Can you please turn up security-related logging? Set the environment variable `GRPC_TRACE` to "transport_security,tsi" and `GRPC_VERBOSITY` to "DEBUG".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The recent versions of the PIP grpcio package (1.23.0) is compiled with an older version of OpenSSL that doesn't properly support ALPN, and GRPC requires ALPN as part of the specification.

If you pip install grpcio~=1.19.0 it will work, due to a different bug -- this version of grpcio doesn't require ALPN at all.

ALPN is a performance improvement only, so disabling it is not a security risk.

Answer (score 1):

If you have control over the server, you should look into enabling ALPN. I was configuring an envoy proxy and came across the same error. Following the instructions on this comment fixed it for me:
https://github.com/envoyproxy/envoy/issues/4291#issuecomment-417292285